# Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorViewEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.0

In my project that was `core 2.2` i have standard service for returning `Razor View` as string (i needed it to generate pdf in my client written in `WPF`):

```
public class RaportService : IRaportService
    {
        private readonly IProjectRepository projectRepository;
        private readonly IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public RaportService(
            IProjectRepository projectRepository,
            IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
            this.razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
            this.tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<string> GenerateProjectRaport(int projectId)
        {
            var project = await this.projectRepository.GetProjectWithTasksAsync(projectId)
                ?? throw new EntityNotFoundException();

            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = this.serviceProvider };
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                string viewPath = "~/wwwroot/RaportTemplate.cshtml";

                var viewResult = this.razorViewEngine.GetView(viewPath, viewPath, false);

                var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = new RaportViewModel
                    {
                        Project = project,
                        ProjectTasks = project.Tasks.ToList(),
                        ProjectEndedTasks = project.EndedTasks.ToList(),
                    }
                };

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, this.tempDataProvider),
                    stringWriter,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions());

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

In `Core 2.2` everything work fine. When i updated my project to `Core 3.0` i get this error:

```
{
    "stackTrace":"   at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerBase.GetHandler[THandler](ServiceFactory factory)\r\n   
at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Handle>g__Handler|0()\r\n   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)\r\n   
at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)\r\n  
 at TaskManager.Api.Controllers.RaportController.GetProjectRaport(Int32 projectId) in C:\\Users\\Michał\\Source\\Repos\\michasacuer\\TaskManager\\Src\\Web\\TaskManager.Api\\Controllers\\RaportController.cs:line 12\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )\r\n   
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n  
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n  
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)",
    "message":"Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[TaskManager.Application.Raport.Queries.GetProjectRaport.GetProjectRaportQuery,System.String]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples."}
```

Even when i register that `IRazorViewEngine` interface and class in `Startup` it still throwing, thtat he need something that calls `IRazorPageFactoryProvider` but i dont know, what is an implementation of it.

So how to get Razor View Engine working with `.NET Core 3.0`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found solution. When you want to acces to `RazorViewEngine` in `.Net Core 3.0` (especially in WebApi) add this two lines into your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages();
```

Comment: What a life saver. Spent the last couple hours trying to track this exact thing down!

Comment: I have an API in net core 3.0, migrated it to 6.0 and now I get this issue. My site does not have Razor pages, it uses angular, how come this error is thrown now? Should I use your solution even if i'm not using views nor razor?

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to access the `RazorViewEngine` you can use the `AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine()`. Now you can access it everywhere you want just using the DI

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ...
    services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add the required services. The following code does the job. In Startup.cs, the trick is to get the `builder` from `AddMvcCore()` or `AddMvc` and then call `AddRazorViewEngine`

```
var builder = services.AddMvcCore();
builder.AddRazorViewEngine();
```